# Prove differentiability of $f$ defined on $\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ by $f(x)=\frac{\ln\left(\cos^2(x)\right)}{\ln\left(x^3\right)}$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

let  $f_1:\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right),  f_1(x)=\left(\frac{\ln\left(\cos^2(x)\right)}{\ln\left(x^3\right)}\right)$

I want to show that the function is differentiable in the given interval.

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ln(cos^2(x_0 + h))}{ln((x_0+h)^3)}- \frac{ln(cos^2(x_0))}{ln(x_0^3)}$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ln(x_0^3) ln(cos^2(x_0 + h))-ln(x_0 + h)^3ln(cos^2(x_0))}{ln(x_0^3)ln((x_0^3 + h))}$$

I do not know how to simplify the equation better.

**Question**: How can I proof now that the function is differentiable in the given interval ?

Comment: The function is undefined at $x = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct only in theory; in practice, using it is a nightmare. The correct approach is to notice that all the "building blocks" of that function are differentiable, therefore their composition will also be differentiable.

More precisely, $\cos$ is differentiable, so $\cos^2$ will be so, and since $\ln$ is differentiable, so will be $\ln \cos^2 x$. For the denominator, $x^3$ is differentiable, so $\ln x^3$ will be differentiable. Finally, since a fraction of two differentiable functions is again differentiable as long as its denominator is not $0$, your function will be differentiable.

Comment: Your approach is right, but in this case and as Doug M commented, at $x=1$ the function is no defined (vertical asymptote) and $f$ is differentiable in $(0,\pi/2)\setminus \{1\}$.